# C9 created workspace before repository

Tags: github, cloud9-ide

I made the mistake of creating a workspace before a repository on [C9.io](https://c9.io/).

As a result I do not have version control. Naturally, I want to use **Git** for my project before make any more changes. Everything I have tried has failed. I would rather not have to copy all the code I've made into a new work space with an already set up repository. So if anyone has any suggestions or answers to this problem, via Command line, GUI or anything else that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

cloud9 doesn't do any special magic when cloning from a git repository, and you can add a remote the standard way you would do locally:

`git init` initialize a git repository in the current folder
`git add -a` add everything (or what you want)
`git commit -m "initial commit"` commit
`git remote add origin git@github.com:<me>/<repo>.git` add your repo
`git push origin HEAD:master` push `HEAD` to `master` branch in the remote you just added